# shape of a sparse tensor without invoking run()

Tags: tensorflow

sparse tensor.shape method returns a tensor object which seems to be of no use to extract the actual shape of the sparse tensor without resorting to run function.

To clarify what I mean, first consider a sparse tensor:

a = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1]], values=[1.0+2j, 2.0], shape=[3, 4, 2])

a.shape returns:

tf.Tensor 'SparseTensor_1/shape:0' shape=(3,) dtype=int64

This is kind of no use.

Now, consider a dense tensor:

a = tf.constant(np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, (4, 4)).astype(dtype=np.complex128))

a.get_shape() returns:
TensorShape([Dimension(4), Dimension(4)])

I can use this output and cast it into a list or tuple of integers without ever invoking run(). However, I cannot do the same for sparse tensor, unless I first convert sparse tensor to dense (which is not implemented for complex sparse tensor yet) and then call get_shape() method on it, but this is kind of redundant, defeats the purpose of using a sparse tensor in the first place and also leads to error down the road if the input sparse tensor is complex.

Is there a way to obtain the shape of a sparse tensor without invoking run() or converting it to a dense tensor first?

Comment: hi QED, have you got an example where you want to use the shape of your sparse tensor ? I suppose that is for define a Tensorflow op or variable ?

Comment: I don't see the problem. You can call `a.get_shape()` on a sparse tensor and get the same information as the dense version.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.SparseTensor` is implemented as a triple of dense Tensors under the hood. The `shape` of a SparseTensor is just a Tensor; if you want to know its value, your best bet is to evaluate it using `session.run`:

```
print(sess.run(a.shape))
```

In general, Tensorflow does not promise to compute an exact shape even for dense tensors at graph construction time; shapes are best effort and may not even have a fixed value. So even for a dense Tensor you may have to evaluate the Tensor using `run` to get a precise shape.